# How can I get the ID from checkbox of <div> framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, checkbox

I am doing a seat reservation project , but i am using a  framework for checkbox to doing this. Now I am trying to save the row and column of each seat into SESSION but error Notice: Undefined index: is occur.

Here is where the code of checkbox I am using: [Seat reservation code](http://codepen.io/hectorfeliz/pen/QbvXLo).

I did try to code like this to get the name of each seat.

HTML:

```
<form method="GET">
    <div id="1_2" role="checkbox" value="80" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber" name="A2html" method="GET">2</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["btnCheckout"]))
    {
        $A2php = $_GET['id'];
        $_SESSION["A2"] = $A2php;
        print_r($_SESSION["A2"]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have to use your field name `$_POST['A2html']`

Comment: Also note: a checkbox value is only send if the box was actually checked. It is not sufficient to check "submit button", you'll also have to check the existence of the checkbox value.

Comment: Thanks for help but $_POST['A2html'] is not working. I also try to use GET to get the id 1_2 but the error ramain.

Comment: id is not used for forms but name is. so with the example above it would be $_GET["A2html"]. also check if the value is in the resulting url as a param